# jest spy / mock function not working as expected when using resetModules

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I've got an interesting scenario which I find hard to describe so haven't yet been able to find out why this is happening. I've got a function that mutates some local state so between tests I reimport the function and use `resetModules` ([jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules)), I'm also trying to spy on a function call within that function. The issue is the spied on function correctly mocks and gets called but the calls don't appear to register causing the second test to fail.

I can get this working by reimporting `logTotal` before each test and reassigning it just as I did with `add`, but I'd like to know why it has to be this way.

```js
// add.js
const { logTotal } = require('./logTotal');

let total = 0;

const add = () => {
  ++total;
  logTotal(total);

  return total;
};

module.exports = {
  add,
};
```

```js
// logTotal.js

const logTotal = (number) => console.log(number);

module.exports = {
  logTotal,
};
```

```js
// add.test.js

const logger = require('./logTotal');

jest.mock('./logTotal', () => {
  return {
    logTotal: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => console.log('hello')),
  };
});

describe('add', () => {
  let add;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const addModule = await require('./add');
    add = addModule.add;
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('should return one if called once', () => {
    const result = add();
    expect(result).toBe(1);
    // This will log [ [ 1 ] ]
    console.log(logger.logTotal.mock.calls);
    expect(logger.logTotal).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should return two if called twice', () => {
    add();
    const result = add();
    expect(result).toBe(2);
    // This will log []
    console.log(logger.logTotal.mock.calls);
    expect(logger.logTotal).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: Does it work better if you just import `add` once?  I don't understand your reasoning for importing it for each test.

Comment: `add` needs to be imported before each test because it mutates `total`. If it wasn't reimported on the second test `total` would already be at `1` which would cause tests to fail.